# Paperclip with legacy database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am having legacy database 
I wanted use paperclip gem for uploading image
paperclip need four parameters for working
But I am having only one field i.e file name and rest all parameters not in database 
So how can i integrate paperclip using single parameter
Following is my code in model

```
class ItemMaster < ActiveRecord::Base

  set_table_name "MDIMT"

  attr_accessible :IMTNAME, :IMTBRIEFDESC, :IMTDETAILDESC, :IMTIMAGE, :IMTCALORIE, :IMTIMTEMCODE1, :IMTIMTEMCODE2,
                  :IMTPRICE, :IMTISVARPRICE, :IMTISCUSTOMIZED, :IMTDURATIONMINS, :IMTSEQNUM, :CREATEDBY, :MODIFIEDBY, 
                  :CREATEDATE, :MODIFYDATE, :EXTRAFIELD1, :EXTRAFIELD2, :EXTRAFIELD3, :EXTRAFIELD4, :IMTISACTIVE, :IMTTAX1,
                  :IMTTAX2, :IMTTAX3, :IMTTAX4, :IMTCNDITEMTYPE, :IMTCNDFILTEROPT
  alias_attribute :image_file_name, :IMTIMAGE  
  has_attached_file :image,
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/:basename.:extension",
                    :url => "/assets/images/:basename.:extension" 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Paperclip uses standard getters and setters to store or receive values from the instance. You cloud try to overload the getters and setters and instead store the data in a serialized hash:

```
class ItemMaster < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "MDIMT"

  attr_accessible :IMTNAME, :IMTBRIEFDESC, :IMTDETAILDESC, :IMTIMAGE, :IMTCALORIE, :IMTIMTEMCODE1, :IMTIMTEMCODE2,
                  :IMTPRICE, :IMTISVARPRICE, :IMTISCUSTOMIZED, :IMTDURATIONMINS, :IMTSEQNUM, :CREATEDBY, :MODIFIEDBY, 
                  :CREATEDATE, :MODIFYDATE, :EXTRAFIELD1, :EXTRAFIELD2, :EXTRAFIELD3, :EXTRAFIELD4, :IMTISACTIVE, :IMTTAX1,
                  :IMTTAX2, :IMTTAX3, :IMTTAX4, :IMTCNDITEMTYPE, :IMTCNDFILTEROPT

  alias_attribute   :image_hash, :IMTIMAGE
  default_value_for :image_hash, {}
  serialize         :image_hash, Hash

  has_attached_file :image,
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/:basename.:extension",
                    :url => "/assets/images/:basename.:extension"

  %w[ image_file_name image_file_size image_content_type image_processing image_updated_at ].each do |field|

    # Adds getter and setter for all keys in the array and stored the data in the image_hash instead
    class_eval <<-END_OF_RUBY, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1

      def #{field}
        image_hash['#{field}']
      end

      def #{field}=(value)
        self.image_hash['#{field}'] = value
      end

    END_OF_RUBY
  end
end
```

Comment: But gives Error private method `image_hash' called for #<ItemMaster:0xc181df0>

Comment: I have included default_value_for gem also

Comment: @Kiran: I removed the `private` method `image_hash` from the code and added instead the declaration `default_value_for :image_hash, {}`. Please try again. Note that I did not test that code, it is just a concept. But I am pretty sure it is close to a working solution.

Comment: It gives following error.
undefined local variable or method `field' for #<ItemMaster:0xb4e42744>

Comment: @Kiran: You are right. I fixed both methods generated with meta programming: `[field]` needed to be `['#{field}']`

Comment: I have checked it 
It gives following error

IndexError in Admin::ItemMastersController#update
string not matched
Rails.root: /home/kiran/Desktop/menudroid_tab
app/models/item_master.rb:80:in `[]='
app/models/item_master.rb:80:in `image_file_name='